# 2D convex hull collision responses

Tags: xna, response, collision, game-physics, convex-hull

I'm trying to make a 2D game using convex hulls for bounding volumes in a discrete physics system but I cannot seem to get the collision responses to work anywhere near what they should be doing. I don't know if my googlefu is lacking or there's just nothing out there but I can't find anything about the responses (there's plenty on generating the hulls). Does anyone have any tips for getting started on this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you suspect about a particular spot of your code you can post it too. Maybe someone can help you

Comment: This is typically something you would use a physics engine for.

Comment: @Jon, it sounds like he is trying to roll his own physics solution, so he may have a reason for not using a physics engine to begin with.

Comment: Has your googlefu already pointed you to this? http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html and this http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/